# What does the function fullName.indexOf(",") != -1 do?

Tags: java

Im trying to solve a problem that asks for these perimeters:

"*A String variable, fullName, contains a name in one of two formats:
last name,  first name (comma followed by a blank), or
first name  last name (single blank)
Extract the first name into the String variable firstName and the last name into the String variable lastName. Assume the variables have been declared and fullName already initialized. You may also declare any other necessary variables.*"

My question is why does the `fullName.indexOf(",") != -1` part work? What does it do? Can someone explain negative index to me? Because from what I see the index of a comma in the fullName would be a lot more than -1 since it is in the middle of the sentence

This is the code I found to answer it:

```
if (fullName.indexOf(",") != -1){

    lastName = fullName.substring(0, fullName.indexOf(","));
    firstName = fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(",") +2 , fullName.length());
}

else{

    firstName= fullName.substring(0, fullName.indexOf(" "));
    lastName= fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ")+1, fullName.length());
}
```

Comment: its simple, when a string does not contain given substring or character Java will return -1. So the code is performing a basic check that "," must exist.

Comment: For substrings having single char use method accepting char: `fullName.indexOf(',')`, it will improve performance

Comment: It is a less clear way of writing `fullName.contains(",")`.

Answer (score 2):

The method [String.indexOf(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) returns :

- the index of the first occurrence of the specified substring,
- or `-1` if there is no such occurrence.

So your code means :

```
if(fullName contains a comma){
    // create lastName firstName from the index of the comma
}else{
    // create lastName firstName from the index of the the space
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fullName.indexOf(",")` will return the index where the `,` character appeared in the fullname String. if it returns `-1` this means there is no `,` character in your string.
by this `if` statement, developer wants to find whether the full name format is "**LastName, FirstName**" or "**FirstName LastName**".

Answer (score 0):

`String.indexOf(char c)`

**Description:**
This method returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character or -1, if the character does not occur.

**Example**

```
String test = "he,llo";                       // 0 1 2 3 4 5
int index = test.indexOf(','); //This returns 2 [h e , l l o]

String test = ",hello";                       // 0 1 2 3 4 5
int index = test.indexOf(','); //This returns 0 [, h e l l o]

String test = "hello";                         // 0 1 2 3 4
int index = test.indexOf(','); //This returns -1 [h e l l o] because it did not find any match of the specified character and therefore I can not assign it a position
```

---

Assuming you only go to a name and a surname, you can delete the spaces with the `trim()` method and then use the `split(char)` method to get the two corresponding parts

```
String name = "Jhon, Beuler";

String firstName = splitName(name)[0]; //First part of String (Jhon)
String lastName = splitName(name)[1]; //Seond part of String (Beuler)

public static String[] splitName(String name)
{
   return name.trim().split(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> Because from what I see the index of a comma in the fullName would be a lot more than -1 since it is in the middle of the sentence

The `!=` checks whether the found index is 0 or higher and thus not -1. Thus whether there is a comma. If there is a comma you split by that. If there is not you split using a space.

Answer (score 0):

It is a less clear way of writing `fullName.contains(",")`. Indeed, if you look at the source code of `String.contains`, you will find this is basically how it is implemented.

But it's occasionally useful to write it like this: if you store the value in a variable, you can avoid repeatedly evaluating it, which may have a substantial cost of you are doing it on a big string:

```
int comma = fullName.indexOf(",");
if (comma != -1){

    lastName = fullName.substring(0, comma);
    firstName = fullName.substring(comma +2 , fullName.length());
}
```